# Is the USB NIC radio toggle controlled via the registry in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, hibernate, network-adapter

I have a Panda Wireless PAU05 802.11n USB stick.  In my Windows 7 laptop, when I close the lid the laptop hibernates and when I resume the wireless radio is always reset to disabled (see image).

Can I write a script or change a registry setting to toggle this value on resume somehow?

[image: PAU05 properties after Win7 resume from hibernation]

Comment: See this....http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-xp-tips/prevent-windows-from-powering-off-usb-device/

Comment: Also some PC's have usb ports that stay powered on even if you shut down, sleep or hibernate, use that port if it has one.

Comment: @Moab - The power management tab is already unchecked for that.  But this issue seems different.  Even if I unplug and plug it back in after a resume that property does not change to 'Enable'  I dont know why the setting is toggled with Hibernation

Comment: Evidently it is written into the driver for that device, have you looked for a newer driver for it?

Comment: Yes it has the latest driver from the chipset manufacturer.  I'm really just looking for a way to automatically change the setting in the registry on resume, the driver is crap for Win7 and am fairly sure it won't be fixed.